# Can FreeNAS zfs send to a Linux machine?

Tags: zfs, truenas, zfsonlinux

I have a FreeNAS 11.2 box. I'd like to use `zfs send` to send snapshots to another box.

Can that receiving box be a Linux machine or does it need to be FreeBSD?

What if the FS is encrypted using FreeNAS's GELI scheme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely send ZFS snapshots and filesystem streams to other ZFS-based systems. There's nothing that would prevent this.

As for the usability of the encrypted filesystem on the target (receiving) server, I don't think that will work.

You're welcome to try this. Is there any reason you haven't tested yet?

Comment: The encryption won't matter.  GELI just encrypts the data blocks stored on the disk.  Once you're running the OS live from the encrypted filesystem, the snapshot is just a snapshot.  I second your encouragement that the OP test.

Comment: Testing likely means building another box. That means buying hardware. I asked this question because it will inform the type of hardware I'd buy.